# Changing html content back and forth with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I want to use jQuery to dynamically change an html element every time it's clicked, back and forth (from A to B to A to B etc...)

Right now I use an empty `<div>` that is filled with jQuery:

```
$('#cf_onclick').append('<h2>A</h2>');
```

And then changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
$("#cf_onclick").html("<h2>B</h2>");
});
});
```

But I cannot figure out how to move it back to `<h2>A</h2>`. I am guessing that `.empty()` jQuery function might work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the [`.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), and trigger it for the first time as well

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#cf_onclick").toggle(
        function(){$(this).html("<h2>A</h2>");},
        function(){$(this).html("<h2>B</h2>");}
    ).click();
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ufXxb/

---

Alternatively you could create two `h2` tags and just alternate between them.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#cf_onclick').append('<h2>A</h2><h2 style="display:none">B</h2>');
    $("#cf_onclick").click(function(){
        $('h2', this).toggle();
    });
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ufXxb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the toggle() function: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/  It's a way of alternating an action with each click.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    var currentOpt =  $("#cf_onclick h2").html();
    currentOpt = (currentOpt == 'B' ? 'A' : 'B');
    $("#cf_onclick").html("<h2>"+currentOpt+"</h2>");
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works too, but `toggle()` function, that I did not knew, is more logical in this case. Thank you anyway!