# Changing the html content back and forth of an tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following checkbox:

```
<form action="">
   <input type="checkbox" id = "hide-completed" name="vehicle" value="Car">
   <span id =  'checkbox-label'> Hide completed tasks</span>
</form>
```

I want the span content to say "Hide completed tasks" when the checkbox is unchecked and "Show completed tasks" when the checkbox is checked.

Possible duplicated questions:
I have seen the following 2 questions:

[Changing html content back and forth with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924672/changing-html-content-back-and-forth-with-jquery)

[Where has fn.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject)...) gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone)

The method suggested on the first link (toggle handlers) is deprecated and the replacements suggested on the second link are not working for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the checked/unchecked status in change event of checkbox, and then append the content based on that:

```
$('#hide-completed').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? 'Show completed tasks' : 'Hide completed tasks';
  $('#checkbox-label').text(c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [change event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/) along with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to do it

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  //change handler for the checkbox
  $('#hide-completed').change(function() {
    //set the text based on the checked state of the checkbox
    $('#checkbox-label').text(this.checked ? 'Show completed tasks' : 'Hide completed tasks')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide-completed" name="vehicle" value="Car" />
  <span id='checkbox-label'> Hide completed tasks</span>
</form>
```